# SAP Business Connector Version 4.8

Tags: coldfusion, saprfc, sap-basis, idoc

It would be helpful if anybody can share ideas regarding SAP Business Connector Version 4.8. Is this out dated or still using?
How could we integrate this using Coldfusion programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can download SAP BC 4.8 from https://support.sap.com/swdc
By https://support.sap.com/pam end of mainstream maintenance 31.12.2020.

Answer (score 0):

Though SAP BC is still supported, this is only for existing customers while they transition to SAP PI which is what they recommend.

Comment: Thanks. Where could find more information regarding the installation
and usage of SAP PI? not able to access SAP business connector 'service.sap.com/sbc-download' 
for new users

Comment: I would recommend you use SCN, you will find all the info you need there.</N>Note SAP is terrible on product naming so they recently renamed it Process Orchestration, so just be aware that is the newest version of the PI.                 [link](https://www.sap.com/community/topic/process-orchestration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the current information at SAP Support:

> End of Mainstream Maintenance: 31.12.2027
>
> [image: SAP for ME - End of mainstream maintenance 31.12.2020]

You can find all answers to your question in the [SAP BC FAQ](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/bc.html):
[image]

In the FAQ, you may find information about SAP PI/XI/PO:

> *"What is the positioning of SAP BC vs. SAP Process Orchestration? See [SAP Note 507813](https://me.sap.com/notes/507813) which describes the positioning of SAP BC vs. SAP Process Orchestration (formerly SAP Exchange Infrastructure)."*

You can see in the note that the position of SAP was in 2002, SAP don't say that SAP BC is obsolete or will be discarded, they just say that SAP PO is the "tool of choice" compared to SAP BC. As I said above the current End of Mainstream Maintenance of SAP BC is 31.12.2027.